# Extract javascript source code as text using R

Tags: javascript, r, xpath, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to extract a code (here: 3121040070932) from this [webpage](https://www.conforama.fr/petit-electromenager/beaute-et-bien-etre/lisseur-fer-brosse/brosse-soufflante-calor-cf6220c0-express-air-brush/p/687739) that is using what it looks like Javascript:

```
<body class=" language-fr">

   <script data-fstrz-fragment-selector="script:contains(var tc_vars)" data-fstrz-fragment-id="fstrz-scss-12" type="text/javascript">

...

      tc_vars['productDeliveryTime'] = undefined;
      tc_vars['productEAN'] = '3121040070932';
      tc_vars['productIsPriceReduced'] = 'true';
   </script>
```

I am using R and I have tried getting the source page using download.file() to extract the source code downloaded as text and then apply regex. But the downloaded file does not seem to contain the Javascript part.

I have read about the v8 package for JavaScript [here](https://datascienceplus.com/scraping-javascript-rendered-web-content-using-r/) and tried to apply the example as below but I can't extract anything:

```
library(rvest)
library(V8)
link <- 'https://www.conforama.fr/petit-electromenager/beaute-et-bien-etre/lisseur-fer-brosse/brosse-soufflante-calor-cf6220c0-express-air-brush/p/687739'
EANcode<- read_html(link) %>% html_nodes('body') %>% html_nodes('script') %>% html_text()
ct <- v8()
read_html(ct$eval(gsub('document.write','',EANcode))) %>% 
 html_text()
```

Help much appreciated!

Comment: Site is protected by Incapsula you could try browser automation - not sure if Incapsula also catches that. However, if they have gone to this length then it is probably against T&Cs of service.

Comment: Interesting!Where did you find that info of Incapsula ?

Comment: I saw it in the response